# Gradle build in docker is too slow

Tags: docker, gradle

I want to build a spring boot application image using Docker's multi-stage build.

My Dockerfile is as follows.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine AS builder

# set arg
ARG WORKSPACE=/workspace
ARG TARGET=${WORKSPACE}/api/build/libs/dependency
ARG PHASE=test

# build only dependency
WORKDIR ${WORKSPACE}
COPY ../build.gradle ../settings.gradle.kts ../gradle.properties ../gradlew ${WORKSPACE}
COPY ../gradle ${WORKSPACE}/gradle

RUN ${WORKSPACE}/gradlew build || return 0 

# copy source code & build
COPY .. .
RUN ${WORKSPACE}/gradlew :api:build -Dspring.profiles.active=${PHASE}
RUN mkdir -p ${TARGET} && (cd ${TARGET}; jar -xf ../*.jar)



FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# copy build 
ARG TARGET=${WORKSPACE}/api/build/libs/dependency
ARG DEPLOY_PATH=/deploy
COPY --from=builder ${TARGET}/BOOT-INF/lib ${DEPLOY_PATH}/lib
COPY --from=builder ${TARGET}/META-INF ${DEPLOY_PATH}/META-INF
COPY --from=builder ${TARGET}/BOOT-INF/classes ${DEPLOY_PATH}

# entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","hello.Application"]
```

**However, gradle build is too slow. It's almost over 20 minutes.**
[image]

In local, gradle build usually takes about 10 minutes.
**Why is gradle build so slow in docker?**

Comment: Check your internet connectivity, docker hosted machine hardware resources.